# Css Hover <a> inside <td>

Tags: html, css, hover

I had a table, inside the tr there are td which there is a link. well, i want to make a class that can change the color the link inside the td. here is my code:

```
<style>
    .dihover{transition: .5s;}
    .dihover:hover{background-color:#B7192A; color: white; cursor: pointer;}
    a.setan{color:#7E7E7E;}
    .setan:hover{color:white;}
    tr.dihover a:hover{color:white;}
</style>  

<table>
    <tr class="dihover">
        <td><a class="setan">this supposed to change colors</a></td>
        <td><a class="setan">this supposed to change colors</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

what did i do wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/g92x5n8s/

Comment: this is working fine http://jsfiddle.net/g92x5n8s/1/

Comment: no, i mean when i hover the row, the link color changes automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to modify your code..check if it is what you require.
**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr class= setan>
    <td><a>this supposed to change colors</a></td>
    <td><a>this supposed to change colors</a></td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
    .dihover{transition: .5s;}
    .dihover:hover{background-color:#B7192A; color: white; cursor: pointer;}
    a.setan{color:#7E7E7E;}
    .setan:hover{color:white;}
    tr.dihover a:hover{color:white;}
</style>
```

Comment: thank you, but what i meant to ask is when i hover the row, the link color changes automatically. not when i hover the link.

Comment: oh sorry im new here (y) thanks by the way